# React app showing only white screen after loading style.css file

Tags: css, reactjs

I am working on react app. Everything was going good but after when I import style.css file from my src folder, it was showing me only white screen.

I have assets folder in src and then in assets folder, there is css folder and then in css folder, there is style.css

I have import the style.css in App.js file like this:

```
import './assets/css/style.css';
import Preloader from "./Components/preloader";
import Header from "./Components/header";
import Menu from "./Components/menu";
import About from "./Components/about";
import CalltoAction from "./Components/calltoaction";
import Blog from "./Components/blog";
import Counter from "./Components/counter";
import Counter2 from "./Components/counter2";
import Contact from "./Components/contact";
import Googlemap from "./Components/googlemap";
import Footer from "./Components/footer";
import Chaticon from "./Components/chaticon";



function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Preloader/>
      <Header/>
      <Menu/>
      <About/>
      <CalltoAction/>
      <Blog/>
      <Counter/>
      <Counter2/>
      <Contact/>
      <Googlemap/>
      <Footer/>
      <Chaticon/>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It is giving the following output:

Compiled successfully!

You can now view aim in the browser.

Local:            http://localhost:3000
On Your Network:  http://192.168.56.1:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully

But showing only white screen.

First I kept src folder in public, at that time too, it was not working.

One thing to mention  is that I am not using any routes, I think so that this is not making any problem.
I looked into different stack overflow questions but unable to configure out my problem.

Comment: Use your developer console to see if there are network request errors, like if you mistyped the path to the css file or if something else went wrong